# How to populate values to Map of a POJO in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

I have a Java class that looks like this.

```
class Student {
    private String studeID;
    private String UUID;
    private Map<String,Object> attributes;
}
```

And I have SQL to get students as follows.

```
SELECT studeID, UUID, F_NAME, L_NAME, PHONE FROM STUDENTS;
```

Need to populate  `F_NAME, L_NAME, PHONE` to `Map<String,Object> attributes` of class `Student`.

How can I achieve this in iBatis/MyBatis XML.

Comment: Define a `<resultMap />` with an `<association />`. Please see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps). If you have any difficulty, add the details to the question.